# Office Add-in: How to control ribbon buttons from add-in panel

Tags: office-addins

I'm developing an Office add-in. I want to make some buttons in the panel so that when I click them, they act like default Office buttons.

Eg: when I click the "Text box" button in the panel, Office will select the "Text box" button, too. How can I do that?

[My add-in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzQe8.png)